Maintenance Mode Custom Message in Frappe ERPNext
I'm trying to change the message for ERPNext Maintenance Mode as it's currently displaying:
"Your system is being updated. Please refresh again after a few moments" 
and I want to change it to:
"Your system is being updated. Please contact administrator if it remains the same" 
I found that this message is under:
frappe\frappe\utils\response.py 
I tried changing it to something else, but the custom message is not being displayed, and it is still displaying the same old message.
I tried these commands also but still no luck:
bench setup nginx
sudo service nginx restart
sudo service nginx reload

I can see that this message is also under frappe\frappe\translations\xxx.csv or frappe\frappe\locale\xxx.csvbut I'm using english so it should not affect (maybe).
Can anyone please help what I'm missing or guide me how to change this message?

Try running this command:
bench --site {sitename} migrate
bench start  

If your custom message is still not appearing, you may need to override that method using hooks.py.

If you have found the file that contains the message, then the best step you can take is to overrides the doc into your application, don't forget to add hooks for the overrides class
